# Numerical integration. Formula explanation?!

Tags: integration, numerical-methods

Can someone explain how to do such transformation? It is similar to Rectangle method but I cannot get last expression.

$$\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} \dfrac{f(x)}{\sqrt{x}}dx \approx \int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} \dfrac{f(z_i)}{\sqrt{x_i}}dx = f(z_i)\dfrac{2h}{\sqrt{x_{i-1}} + \sqrt{x_{i}} }$$ where $z_i = \dfrac{x_{i-1}+x_i}{2}$

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

This is just simple integration plus binomial formulas:
$$
\int_a^b\frac{dx}{\sqrt x}=[2\sqrt x]_a^b=2(\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a})=\frac{2(b-a)}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}}
$$

And the first transformation is the weighted mean value theorem approximated by the most typical value for the midpoint.

Comment: Many thanks to You!
its really simple..)